# Implementing parsing with the ls command in C

Tags: c, linux, parsing, directory, ls

I'm trying to implement the `ls` command in C with a few parameters like `-a`, `-l`... or `-la`, but I'm having issues with the parsing, when I use the input I get Segmentation Fault, this is an example of the `-a` parameter:

```
int comparator(char *av) {
    int i = 0;
    if (my_strcmp((av[i]), "-a") == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

int my_ls_a(char *path) {
    int comp = comparator(path);
    DIR *pdirec = opendir(".");
    struct dirent *direc;
    direc = readdir(pdirec);
    
    while (direc != NULL || comp == 0) {
        my_printf("%s  ", direc->d_name);
        direc = readdir(pdirec);
    }
    if ((path = readdir(pdirec)) == NULL)
        my_printf("\n");
    if (pdirec == NULL)
        return (84);
    closedir(pdirec);
    return (0);
}
```

And this is my main:

```
int main(int ac, char *av[]) {  
    if (ac == 1)
        my_ls_a(av[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

I already have all the `#include` in a .h by the way.

When I only use the `main` function it works but not when I add the parameter `-a`.

Comment: Why are you passing the command name to the `my_ls_a()` function?  Where are you parsing the arguments?  There are lots of questions (666 at the moment) that correspond to searching on SO with the search term "`[c] getopt`" which would collectively (or selectively) teach you about how to parse command line arguments.  Don't think of parsing command line arguments without the use of a function, IMNSHO.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to use [`getopt()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/getopt-function-in-c-to-parse-command-line-arguments/) for parameter parsing instead of writing your own parser.

Comment: Yes I know but It's a project for scholl and we can't use it, only the opendir, readir, stat, lstat and a few other libs.

Answer (score 0):

You have undefined behavior in the function `comparator` in `my_strcmp((av[i]), "-a")` because `av` is defined as a `char *` so you are passing a character where `my_strcmp` probably expects a pointer.

You should compile with `-Wall -Werror` to avoid such silly mistakes.

It is unclear why you pass only a single argument to `my_ls_a`. You should pass both `ac` and the argument array `av` and iterate on the arguments to parse the options.

Comment: I alredy use -Wall -Weror, the thing is that if I use the comparator function it will work, but I can't do that with every paramerts, because my fucntion should be lower than 20 lines.

Comment: @Molaryy: Do you understand the problem I pointed to?

Comment: Yes, I immediatly searched what you suggested me, I think I didn't used the good questions.